# CSS multiple different position : absolute buttons screen resolution problem

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have three buttons with `position: absolute` , with three different positions.

But in different resolution, all the buttons aren't positioning properly.

```css
.row {
  padding: 10%;
}

.button-group {
  position: relative;
}

.button1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.button2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 280px;
}

.button3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary button1">BUTTON 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger button2">BUTTON 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success button3">BUTTON 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Here is the [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/207520/) .

EDIT:

Properly positioning should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzNdZ.jpg)

But in lower resolution it is looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtZ2H.jpg)
and higher resolution, it is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J47xe.jpg)

Comment: this is then a good example that shows you how bad is using position:absolute to create layout

Comment: can u add more info about, at which resolution it's failing or causing issues?

Comment: What do you mean properly? How is it supposed to look?

Comment: This is a bad practice to expect the same structure in different devices. Usually the default css works for 100% viewport width or the parents with. But when you have a fixed width it will misbehave in responsive. Inorder keep the same structure you need write responsive for each and every device's width which impossible. Or you can use a percentage value.But still it's not a good practice. I suggest you to make a different design for smaller devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses.

But I solved this problem by giving `position: absolute` to `.button-group` and `position: relative` to all the `button classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving fixed numbers to the width and height such as:

```
width:200px;

height:200px;
```

You better use percentage so it can adjust its width according to its parent container.

```
width:50%;
height:50%
```

Do the same logic for all the code and if you want a different look at different screen size, use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
    width:50%;
}
```

}

Comment: Sizes of the buttons are fixed, I can't change the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

### Button 1 Left Value

You need to add a left position value to keep button one from moving on resize.

```
.button1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

[image]

```css
.button1, .button2, .button3 {display:block;}  
.row {
  padding: 10%;
}

.button-group {
  position: relative;
}

.button1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
    left: 70px;
  
}

.button2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 280px;
}

.button3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary button1">BUTTON 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger button2">BUTTON 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success button3">BUTTON 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```